# Ajax auto refresh & javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, refresh, head

I have a page which reloads a DIV with AJAX every 5 seconds. I also have an AJAX sorting script (you can see it [here](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/02/sort-table-rows-using-ajax.html)). The sorting script works great when I visit the page for first time, but when the page is refreshed it doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong? I have the sorting script in the HEAD tag, and the refresh on the bottom because I want to use some PHP variables there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your refresh code repopulates the `<div>`, it's probably destroying the event handler associations that your table sorter established. Perhaps you need to re-run the table sorter initialization after each refresh.